# page counter on different pages of website

Tags: php, visitors

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$counter_name = "index.txt";
// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}
// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);
// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
  $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
  $counterVal++`enter code here`;
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f); 
}
?>
```

I am using this code to count the number of visitors on one page using sessions. 
But I want to keep page counter on all other pages as well. So when I copy and paste the code into other pages the value does not get incremented. It only gets incremented on first page but not on other page I visit. What is the possible solution?

Comment: There are a number of issues here, but there is no reason why that logic should not work on other pages of your site too. You should however use an absolute path to make sure that all scripts address the same file location in your server side file system.

Comment: for other pages i have different text files that stores the counter value. the problem is once i the session starts on one web page it remains like that when i switch over to other page and hence the other page counter value does not get an increment.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to make any sense of your last comment. If all this is about tracking visitors and numbers, then why don't you simply use an existing and proven solution like `piwik` or an apache log file analyzer? Easier and you gain much more and more precise information.

Comment: all i want is to clear session when i go to different page and start a new session in that page

Comment: Clearing the session for every request in a website is against everything a session is meant for. Why do you use sessions at all then? Anyway, if that is what you want, then you need to use `session_destroy()` which does what its name suggests. Using `session_start()` at the beginning of a script will attach to any already existing session or start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I do this on my website by storing information in a database. It's more secure than using a txt file, so you should consider doing that. And you can use the IP along with SESSION to be more thorough with record keeping. Make a traffic logging file to include in your header file that will use the request URI, IP, session id/user id.

By using request URI you can put the one single traffic logging script on all pages to handle all the different web pages you want to track. I can add some  code examples if you want.

Hope this helps you out!

```
*/ 
Define Variables You Want To Store..In this case it is preparing a timestamp, the page (i.e. the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), and the IP
/*

$time = time();
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//This is used to sort out the correct IP Address to store //

$client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $client;
    } elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $forward;
    } else {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

//Use this if you want to see if the data exists already, I usually just store all traffic to make sure people aren't up to anything fishy//



$stmt = $database->prepare("SELECT ID FROM traffic WHERE IP = :IP AND page = :page");
$stmt->bindParam(':IP', $ip);
$stmt->bindParam(':page', $page);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->FetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!isset($result)) {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO traffic (time,IP,page) VALUES (:time, :ip, :page)";
     $params = array(
             ':time' => $time,
             ':ip' => $ip,
             ':page' => $page,
         );
     $stmt = $database->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. please add some code so that i can understand it properly

Answer (score -2):

You need use in mysql or sqlite or other database server for save a name and number of visits.
You need first of all create database and learn how use it. Don't run....
With TXT files you can't arrive far...